# How to set a reference column into a scatter plot and drawing it with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, scatter

I am trying to make a scatter plot based on x_pos and y_pos to determine the location, but additionally, I want to add an extra variable that would be the year to distinguish within the graph with different colors.

At the end the graph should show a lot of dots of different color for each year

my df is this looks like this:

```
    Year    x_pos   y_pos
0   2015    9229    8469
1   2015    13908   5960
2   2015    8281    7889
3   2015    8522    8895
4   2015    8902    7643
...
423 2018    4170    4983
423 2018    4274    5121
423 2018    3828    5100
423 2018    1236    10532
424 2018    4188    12533
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Kaggle kernel with nice exploratory data analysis (EDA).

https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/simple-exploration-notebook-zillow-prize/notebook

```py
# if you are using Jupyter, then use magic function below
# %matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# kaggle kernel with nice exploratory data analysis (EDA)
# https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/simple-exploration-notebook-zillow-prize/notebook
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.scatterplot(x=df[['x_pos']].values, y=df['y_pos'].values, hue=df['year'].values)
plt.ylabel('y_label here', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('x_label here', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Put your title here', fontsize=15)
plt.legend(loc='upper right', ncol=1)
plt.show()
```